# Get all orders for a customer

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, customer

I want to check if the customer logged in has had at least 1 order over €30 euro. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use functions below

```
/**
 * @param int $customerId
 * @param null|float $grandTotal
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isCustomerHasOrders($customerId, $grandTotal = null)
{
    $orderCollection = $this->getCustomerOrderCollection($customerId, $grandTotal);
    return (bool)$orderCollection->getSize();
}

/**
 * @param int  $customerId
 * @param null $grandTotal
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
 */
public function getCustomerOrderCollection($customerId, $grandTotal = null)
{    
    $orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
        ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ;
    if ($grandTotal && $grandTotal > 0) {
        $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('base_grand_total', array ('gteq' => $grandTotal));
    }
    return $orderCollection;
}
```

You can specify order statuses

```
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
```

Usage

```
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$grandTotal = 30;
if ($this->isCustomerHasOrders($customerId, $grandTotal)) {
    // TODO:
}
```

Comment: can i get the order which has specific product?

Comment: @Hunter It is possible, but you would need to sub-query on the `sales_flat_order_item` table, or `JOIN` that table to add that filter.

Answer (score 8):

This should do it:

```
<?php //filtering the customers by email address
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail(); 

$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email);

//loop through his orders
foreach ($orderCollection as $_order): ?>

    <?php $order_total = $_order->getGrandTotal(); //get order total ?>
    <?php if($order_total > 30): //check total, including shipping ?>
        <p>Hey, this customer has at least one order over 30 euros</p>
        <?php break; //break the loop at first order over 30 ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```